# Classloader + Modules = testing headaches

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have three modules, lets call them "Core", "APIs", and "API".

What do I need to do to make a class from API visible to ClassLoader code in Core?

Core:

```
module Core {
   //requires nothing relevant... org.json, commons.math3
   exports Core.foo;
}
```

API:

```
module API {
   requires Core;
   exports API.bar;
}
```

APIs:

```
module APIs {
  requires transitive Core;
  requires transitive API;

  exports APIs.baz;
}
```

APIs calls a Core function which tries to get a  class by name from API, via `Class.forName("API.bar.someClass")` and promptly throws a `ClassNotFound` exception.  Note that API.bar is indeed exported.

I've tried quite a few things, such as:

- declaring the (already exported) packages open to Core as well.
- Marking all the modules listed above as `open module`.
- Adding `dependencies { testRuntimeOnly project(':API') }` to Core's build.gradle file.

  - Interestingly, `runtime project(':API')` caused a circular dependency.
- Ripping out great big handfuls of hair

**Can anyone explain the cause of this mess?**  It's clearly a class path/module path thing, but I was under the impression that the transitives and exports should take care of all that, and that all these jar files were running within the same java.exe session with a shared module path... so no problem right?  Clearly not.

**What is the solution to this mess?**

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear earlier, but all this is going on within a JUnit 5 test session.

Comment: Just a tip, testing does not have to be modularized. So you can leave everything on the classpath and it should still work

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning, use `ClassLoader` to load classes across modules. Use `Class.forName` only to load classes within the same module. For example try `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("API.bar.someClass")`

Comment: It sounded promising, but using the SystemClassLoader didn't work.  Nor did the PlatformClassLoader.  Got anything else?

Comment: Let me see if I can reproduce this

Comment: Wouldn't this usage require a cyclic dependency, which is what the module system tries to avoid? If `API` needs to call a `Core` function, it must depend on `Core`. Now if `Core` also needs to create a class from `API`,  that mean it also needs to depend on `API` and this will cause a cycle. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Core only needs API at runtime.  If it were at compile time, then yes it would be.

Comment: I am getting quite different results. Checkout this [gradle project](https://github.com/smac89/multi-java9-gradle) and see if that's what you are trying to do. The only thing I had to do was to make sure `API` (appMod) depends on `Core` (coreMod) and that appMod exports the package of the class that coreMod needs to create by reflection. You can import it into IntelliJ and run it. Also there was no need to use `ClassLoader`; it seems to just work

Comment: I'm using gradle 5.2.1 with OpenJDK 11.03.  You?

Comment: Gradle version 5.6.3 with OpenJDK 11. You can see this in the root build.gradle

Comment: Which plugins are you using? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: plugins: java, jacoco, idea

Comment: As @smac89 said: this usage is against the idea of the module system. Core should not know anything about API or APIs.

Comment: @Mark How are you configuring Gradle to use the modulepath? As far as I know, even the latest version of Gradle does not have first class support for Java modules; I don't believe the plugins you have do anything in this regard.

Comment: @tquadrat I don't think `core` necessarily knows anything about the other modules. It seems more like a service-provider setup, though in that case one might as well use `ServiceLoader`.

Comment: @slaw lots of JVM args.  --patch-module and --add-reads and --ad-exports, Oh My!  --module-path and --add-modules and --add-opens, Oh My!  Especially in our test classes, mostly for junit.jupiter's reflection needs.  Which is precisely what Core is doing, reflection.  I thought declaring everything an `open module` would address that, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the dependencies are going only down the tree: APIs requires API requires Core.

That means that Core does not know (and should not know) anything about API nor APIs.

In case Core should manipulate an instance of a Class that is defined in API, Core must provide an Interface `AnInterface` that is implemented by a class from API:

```
public class AClass implements AnInterface {…}
```

Then you can have a method in Core that takes an instance of `AnInterface`:

```
public class CoreClass
{
    public aMethod( AnInterface param ) {…}
}
```

But that means that methods in Core cannot create instances of classes that are defined in API (and for my understanding, that is what you want …).

When I encountered a similar issue, I solved it like this:

1. I defined that already mentioned interface in Core.
2. Next I defined a class `AnInterfaceFactory` that takes an instance of `Supplier` for `AnInterface` instances in Core (or I added that argument to the constructor for a class that needs to create new `AnInterface` instances, or I added that argument to the respective method …)
3. The implementing class in API provides a simple static factory method for an instance of that class, compliant with the `Supplier` interface.

That could look like that:

In Core:

```
public final CoreClass
{
    …
    public final AnInterface createAnInterfaceInstance( Supplier<AnInterface> factory )
    { return factory.get(); }
}
```

In API:

```
public class AClass implements AnInterface
{
    public final static AClass create() { return new AClass(); }
}
```

In (for example) APIs:

```
…
var instance = new CoreClass().createAnInterfaceInstance( AClass::create );
…
```

That works because the method `create()` lives in the context of the module API, but the reference to it can be passed to wherever …

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to tell what exact issue you are facing without more details and/or example code. I have tried to create a minimal, complete example project according to the description in the question and I don’t have any issues building and running the application. Hopefully this example project will help you to get on the right track.

### Project Structure

```
.
├── api
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── api
│               │   └── bar
│               │       └── MyApi.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── apis
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── apis
│               │   └── baz
│               │       └── MyCoreUser.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── build.gradle
├── core
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── core
│               │   └── foo
│               │       └── MyApiReflection.java
│               └── module-info.java
└── settings.gradle
```

(For brevity, this doesn’t show any [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) files.)

### Project Sources

#### `settings.gradle`

```java
include 'core', 'api', 'apis'
```

#### `build.gradle`

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.6.0' apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin'
}

// only needed if you keep "requires core" in module-info.java:
/*
project(':api') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
    }
}
*/

project(':apis') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
        implementation project(':api')
    }
}
```

#### `api/src/main/java/api/bar/MyApi.java`

```java
package api.bar;

public class MyApi {

    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

#### `api/src/main/java/module-info.java`

```java
module api {
    // seemingly not required but would work, too (see also note in build.gradle):
    //requires core;

    exports api.bar;
}
```

#### `apis/src/main/java/apis/baz/MyCoreUser.java`

```java
package apis.baz;

import core.foo.MyApiReflection;

public class MyCoreUser {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(MyApiReflection.callMyApi());
    }
}
```

#### `apis/src/main/java/module-info.java`

```java
module apis {
    requires transitive core;
    requires transitive api;

    exports apis.baz;
}
```

#### `core/src/main/java/core/foo/MyApiReflection.java`

```java
package core.foo;

public class MyApiReflection {

    public static String callMyApi() throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("api.bar.MyApi");
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        return (String) clazz.getMethod("getHello").invoke(instance);
    }
}
```

#### `core/src/main/java/module-info.java`

```java
module core {
    exports core.foo;
}
```

### How to Build/Run

```
$ ./gradlew build
…
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed

$ java \
    --module-path apis/build/libs/apis.jar:core/build/libs/core.jar:api/build/libs/api.jar \
    --module apis/apis.baz.MyCoreUser
hello
```

I have tested this with Gradle 6.0.1 and Java 11.